# Entity Framework 6.1 Unidirectional Navigation Property 0 to Many with Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, entity-framework-migrations, fluent, navigation-properties

I'm new to EF and am having issues trying to create a unidirectional navigation association (0 to many) using the Fluent API. Here are simplified versions of the classes:

```
public partial class Company
{
 public int Id { get; set; }

 // "Company" is NOT REQUIRED to have any BillingInfo records/objects
 public virtual IList<BillingInfo> BillingInfos { get; set; }
}

public partial class BillingInfo
{
 public int Id { get; set; }

 // A "BillingInfo" requires ONE "Company"
 public int Company_Id { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm using EF 6.1 Code First with migrations enabled along with SQL Server 2012.

In my derived EntityTypeConfiguration classes for "Company" and "BillingInfo", I've tried every which way I can think of to achieve:

1. A Company DOES NOT REQUIRE any BillingInfo records, but MAY HAVE MANY.
2. A BillingInfo DOES REQUIRE only ONE Company.
3. Maintain a unidirectional navigation between Company and BillingInfo. (don't want to have a Company navigation property on BillingInfo)
4. EF Migration creates the NON-NULLABLE Company_Id field in database, WITH a defined ForeignKey constraint.

All the methods I've tried, only gets me partially there. The closest I've come is this (but the only thing missing is the foreignkey constraint isn't created):

```
class CompanyConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public CompanyConfig()
    {
        this.HasOptional(company => company.BillingInfos)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("Company_Id"));
    }
}
```

Any ideas???

Comment: I am not sure about fluent api but with models you can do same by changing
public int Company_Id { get; set; } to

public Company Company { get; set; }

Comment: Thank you Anshul, but I want to maintain unidirectional navigation.

Comment: Any particular reason why you dont want bi-directional? If it is performance then you can go through below mentioned link where they had provided kind of heck solution 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: I want to avoid it for reasons of both performance and increased complexity in serializing objects to JSON. With bidirectional navigation, you will have to deal with circular references during serialization.

Comment: Ef recommended way if to use two way navigation, and i guess you should not build you EF model/design keeping in mind serialization, there are many ways to avoid circular reference like use of ScriptIgnore data annotation or 
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Comment: I did just discover the ProxyCreation resolution. Thanks Anshul!

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use the following code:

```
private class CompanyMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
    {
        public CompanyMapping()
        {
            this.HasMany(o => o.BillingInfos).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(fk => fk.Company_Id);
        }
    }
    private class BillingInfoMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<BillingInfo>
    {
        public BillingInfoMapping()
        {
            this.HasOptional(o => o.Company).WithMany(c=>c.BillingInfos).HasForeignKey(fk => fk.Company_Id);
        }
    }
```